# Specifying a Hashable type constraint inside a struct

Tags: swift, types

```swift
protocol Component {}

struct Container {
    let map: [Component: Component]
}
```

In the code above, how can I specify that the keys of `map` may contain any type of `Component`s that are also `Hashable`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```
protocol Component {}

struct Container<T: Hashable & Component> {
    let map: [T: Component]
}
```

Or

```
protocol Component {}

struct Container<T> where T: Hashable, T: Component {
    let map: [T: Component]
}
```